# Ubuntu hangs in "system target reboot" due to kernel problems

Tags: 22.04, lts

i have a problem with rebooting my system.
This remains in the status "Reached system target reboot".
The hardware has the following properties:

- Kontron A-151 EKL
- Intel Atom® x64
- GRAPHICS CORE: Intel® UHD Graphics

Software:

- Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS

After a bit of research I was able to find 2 possible errors.
For the first one, it is recommended to make an entry in grub. Either "acpi-force" or "quiet splash acpi=force" should be entered under the default entry. Unfortunately, neither entry had any effect.

The second possible error says that the current kernel has a problem. The kernel should therefore be downgraded. The actual version was 5.15.0-78-generic. Since version 76 had caused a problem I went down to 75 and executed the following command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.15.0-75-generic
```

After I had installed the package and booted with it, I was actually able to reboot the device afterwards. However, I then realised that I no longer had a network configuration. After further research I came across a post that said something was missing when installing the older kernel. So I ran the following command to install all other packages.

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-75-generic
```

After the installation, the network configuration was available again. However, the reboot error was there again.

Therefore I suspect that something is installed in this "extra" installation that causes this error. I would be very happy if someone has an idea why this error appears :)

Kind Regards
Hotte